# Deriving the gradient of a potential in MATLAB using symbolic toolbox?

Tags: matlab

I want to compute the gradient of the electrostatic potential of combination of 4 charges located at `(1,1,0)`, `(1,-1,0)`, `(-1,1,0)` and `(-1,-1,0)`. How can I use the symbolic toolbox in MATLAB to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

My electromagnetics is rusty, but your question has a simple analytical solution.

The electric potential is:

[image]

and this is what it looks like on the plane `z=0`

[image]

Now the gradient is

[image]

and noting that

[image]

you can easily apply the above to all the terms in the equation of the gradient to get a closed form solution that can be easily plotted.

---

#### In MATLAB:

Here's an example that shows you how to perform the above partial differentiation in MATLAB. You can then build upon this to derive the full solution. I'll leave that upto you.

```
syms x y z x0 y0 z0
diff(1/sqrt((x-x0)^2+(y-y0)^2+(z-z0)^2),x)

ans = 

-(x - x0)/((x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2 + (z - z0)^2)^(3/2)
```

Comment: Hi.I insist on doing this in MATLAB.if it's possible,I'd like to see the contour command you used to plot the above picture.thanks

Comment: @Shabnam: I've provided a small related example of how to use the symbolic toolbox in MATLAB. It's an easy extension from that to the entire problem. The contour plot was made in mathematica. To do it in MATLAB, you can look into the [`contour`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/contour.html) function.